# Mysql can we get all rows with SELECT IN query

Tags: mysql

I was hoping to call a dynamic query in mysql-nodejs

the query is something like this

```
select a 
  from table 
 where startdate = ? 
   and prjId in (?) 
   and loc in (?)
```

there will be 3 parameters

```
`startdate` string
`prjId` array
`loc` array
```

my question is if the array `prjId` is null it should get all project id

same in the case of `loc` also

1. both are null
2. one is not null
3. both arrays are not null

Simply put

`select * from table where name in (?)`

can it return all rows if nothing is given, which I checked (wont work)
But does there exist something like that

thanks

Comment: No.  You'll need to generate the SQL on the fly.  If there is no prjId, then don't add the `and prjId in ?` clause, etc.

Comment: Simply put: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query